# Al agregar un objeto a una array el objeto se modifica

Tags: javascript, google-api

Estoy utilizando la API de Gmail, donde obtengo los mensajes enviados a mi cuenta. Utilizando también las librerías de Google Clientes.
El problema es que al imprimir el valor del objeto devuelto a la consulta solo lo hace si lo imprimo como variable. Si lo meto en una array y lo imprimo por alguna razón me devuelve otro objeto diferente.

De esta forma el objeto se imprime correctamente:

```
    let msg =  gapi.client.request({
      'path': 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/ltomicb@gmail.com/messages/'+msgId[0],
    })

    return msg
  })
  .then(function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
  })
```

Objeto devuelto:

```
body: "{\n  \"id\": \"17befbfa6d794b69\",\n  \"threadId\
headers: {cache-control: 'private', content-encoding: 'gzip', content-length: '6501', content-type: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', date: 'Thu, 16 Sep 2021 18:49:18 GMT', …}
result: {id: '17befbfa6d794b69', threadId: '17befbfa6d794b69', labelIds: Array(3), snippet: 'Se ha concedido el acceso a tu cuenta de Google a …tu cuenta. Comprobar actividad También puedes ver', payload: {…}, …}
status: 200
statusText: null
```

En cambio de esta forma se imprime un objeto diferente que no me sirve:

```
let msgs = [];

let msg =  gapi.client.request({
      'path': 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/ltomicb@gmail.com/messages/'+msgId[0],
    })
    
    msgs.push(msg)

    return msgs
  })
  .then(function(msgs){
    console.log(msgs)
  })
};
```

Array devuelto:

```
 > [$B]
    0: $B
    $a: UB
    $W: false
    Cf: null
    QJ: false
    Qk: "auto"
    VL: false
    Vg: {path: 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/ltomicb@gmail.com/messages/17befbfa6d794b69', method: 'GET', params: {…}, headers: {…}, body: undefined, …}
```

Comment: En los bloques de código falta algo... esos `then` a que pertenecen?

Comment: Pertenecen a una consulta hacia la API de Google Clients. Los {then} pevios no son importantes, pero de todas forma los agrego para que puedas verlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era un problema de asincronía. La variable msg se guardaba como una promesa en lugar del valor que debía devolver. Lo resolví de la siguiente forma:

```
.then(function(msgId){
    let msgs = []
    msgId.forEach(async (id)=>{
      let msg = await gapi.client.request({
      'path': 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/ltomicb@gmail.com/messages/'+id
    });
      msgs.push(msg);
    })

    return msgs
  })
  .then((response)=>{
    console.log(response)
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

Querido amigo, este dilema es conocido como error de sintaxis. Es muy común entre los usuarios que obvian los puntos y comas `;`.

Básicamente tu código bien escrito es el siguiente:

```
let msgs = [];
let msg =  gapi.client.request({
  'path': 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/ltomicb@gmail.com/messages/'+msgId[0]
});
msgs.push(msg);
return msgs;
```

El código que le sigue, sale sobrando porque viene después del ``return`.

```
//esto ya no se toma en cuenta
  })
  .then(function(msgs){
    console.log(msgs)
  })
};
```

Entonces, lo último que se hace con tu código, es retornar el valor de `msgs`, el cual es un array que contiene un solo objeto, y ese objeto es la promesa no resulta de la solicitud al cliente de gapi.

Creo que entiendo cual es tu objetivo, en todo caso, tendría que ser de esta manera:

```
const msgs = [];
gapi.client.request({
  'path': 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages',
}).then(response=>{
  msgs.push(response);
  console.log(msgs);
});
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder pero no es lo que estoy buscando. En este caso solo se podría agregar un elemento al array y hay varios errores. El return en el manejo de promesas sirve para enviar el valor al siguiente then. Además no se puede utilizar una variable declarada en un then en el siguiente como haces con msgs[].